# timeout for blocking TCP socket not working

Tags: sockets, winapi, socket-timeout-exception, winsockets

Please note: the platform is **Windows**, not Linux.

I have a blocking TCP client socket. After connecting to the remote server, I set a read timeout (as the remote server is not stable, the network condition is bad) and then receive data.

Sometimes, the `recv()` function never returns and my program is dead.

The code looks like this:

```
// set timeout
{
    int millisec = 1000;
    if(setsockopt(sock_, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char*)&millisec, sizeof(int))) {
        MessageBox(0, "setsockopt fail", "", 0);
    }
}

unsigned begin_t = time(0);
int r = recv(sock_, ptr, static_cast<int>(size), 0);
unsigned end_t = time(0);

if(end_t - begin_t > 2) {
    MessageBox(0, "over 2 sec", "", 0); // This MessageBox popups some time
}
```

I set the socket timeout to 1 second right before the `recv()` function. In theory, the `recv()` will never take more than 1 second. But sometimes, it still takes over 3 seconds, then the MessageBox appears.

Why is the timeout not working sometimes?

Comment: `time()` has seconds precision, so it is not going to be very accurate for timing code. Use `GetTickCount/64()` or `QueryPerformanceCounter()` instead

Comment: Maybe I don't need to count the time cost, because sometimes it never returns.

Comment: There is simply no way that `recv()` can block forever when a non-infinite `SO_RCVTIMEO` timeout is in effect. So something else is going on.  Also, just FYI, another way to implement a reading timeout is to call `select()` before calling `recv()`.

Comment: Does the socket have the `OVERLAPPED` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SO_RCVTIMEO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinSock/sol-socket-socket-options) is no supported in a blocking socket.

> **If a blocking receive call times out, the connection is in an
>   indeterminate state** and should be closed. If the socket is created
>   using the WSASocket function, then the dwFlags parameter must have the
>   WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED attribute set for the timeout to function
>   properly. Otherwise the timeout never takes effect.

Using the [`WSASocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasocketa) with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`. Or `socket()`(default for `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` mode)

Comment: The key is exactly `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, my code calls `setsockopt(INVALID_SOCKET, SOL_SOCKET, SO_OPENTYPE,...`, The `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is disabled if the `SO_OPENTYPE` is set. The detail can be found her: https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib/issues/150